# Вёрстка спидометра

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Подскажите, как сделать движение этой стрелки? В функцию должна приходить скорость и в зависимости от значения, нужно двигать стрелку.
Пробовал реализовать через offset-path, но получилось довольно криво.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А с `rotate` что?

Comment: rotate просто поворачивает. 
Вместе с offset-path я применял offset-rotate и при помощи этого удалось добиться результата, чтобы стрелка смотрела в нужном направлении, но вопрос в том, как заставить её ровно двигаться по траектории вдоль циферблата :)